# Update Map object that is initialized inside init() and that value coming from sql table

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, dictionary

Hi I have Map object which is getting its values from MySQL table. This map is initialize inside servlet `init()` method in order to save many database call. What if the value in sql table change, can I Update Map object's value without restarting Servlet because `init()` method is called only once. Can I make an update button for this purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to. Assuming your servlet is something like (minus exceptions)

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private volatile Map<String, String> properties;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    public void init() {
        properties = ...; // from jdbc call
    }

    ...
}
```

You will have a `Map` reference in `properties` that can be changed. The dangerous part here is that multiple threads may be accessing the map, so if you want to change it you need to make it `volatile` so that changes are visible to all `Thread`s and you need to synchronize on a lock (or use a `Lock` object) so that `Thread`s wait while changes are being made, if that's required.

For example, you may have an `update` button that performs a `POST`. Your `doPost()` would look something like this

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Map<String, String> newProperties = ...; // get new map from jdbc call
    synchronized (lock) {
        properties = newProperties;
    }
}
```

And that's it. The `properties` map now holds the new up-to-date properties (or whatever) from the database.